# Warning: include(include/about.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\index.php on line 7

Tags: php, xampp

I am facing the problem in my code please help me to get ride of the prob

```
Warning: include(include/about.php): failed to open stream: No such
file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\index.php on line 7

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'include/about.php' for inclusion
(include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\index.php
on line 7
```

Comment: Since the files doesn't exist, delete the lines from the code and your done.

Comment: I was facing the same problem, 
I was importing a `con.php` file in another file. It was throwing an error when I use `con` as the file name which I was importing when I renamed it to `connection.php` and import it again the error was gone. <br>
I think `con` will be a keyword or something else that's why it was showing error.

Answer (score 2):

you need to make sure that the route of the file is correct since is not able to be found.. or remove the code..

Answer (score 1):

You just need to select the right path. So depending on where the file is. maybe you can shed some light as to where your file is located and where the file is that you are trying to insert the below code..

```
include(../about.php)
```

Answer (score 1):

'about.php' does not exist in the path you're linking to. Correct the path. 
Here's an example:

```
include '/../about.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, I found that my theme's **functions.php** file had a function that was calling this template. I removed that function and my problem got corrected. This function which I deleted was:

```
/*All jQuery Post should use a different single file*/
add_filter( 'single_template', function ($single_template) {
 global $post;
if ( in_category( 'jquery' ) ) {
      $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-jquery.php';
}
return $single_template;
}, 10, 3 );
/*End*/
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use require instead of include

```
require("handlers/register-handler.php");
```

Mac OS X

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

when i encounter with this error because my file name mistakenly type without .php extension in includes folder.
example :
"inlcude/session.php"
but actual file was " session " without extention .php
i rename " session " with " session.php " error vanished.

Answer (score -1):

Please put the quote in

```
include "include/about.php";
```

Now it should work;

Comment: it has already quote,     if (isset($_GET['about'])) {
   include "include/about.php";
}

Comment: Please check here this will helpfull for you https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: If there were no quotes about the file name, there would be a syntax error printed